# Different test results when project is built in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I have a Spring rest endpoint JUnit test and sometimes I find a strange problem.
When I use Eclipse my test doesn't want to pass. It fails with the following message:

```
caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.package.dto.MyDto: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

And for now everything is clear. That's true that I don't have a default constructor because I use Lombok and my problematic class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyDto {...}
```

But when I use IntelliJ to build the project everything works fine. Even in Eclipse all tests pass when project is rebuild with IntelliJ.
Also when I use console Maven command: `mvn clean install` everything works without any problems.
So it looks like Eclipse build whole project a little bit different. After Eclipse build tests fails in IntelliJ and when using `mvn test` console command.
The question is why it happens? I know how to fix it (by adding default constructor) but I just want to know the difference between Eclipse and other  build tools.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need the lombok plugin to make it work in Eclipse. Else it won't generate the code.

Comment: I have installed Lombok plugin in Eclipse. Should I do some additional configuration?

Comment: Maybe the Lombok version inside Eclipse and the dependency version are different?

Comment: Nope. Eclipse plugin and dependency versions are the same.

Comment: Why downvoted? I would like to know what's wrong with my question

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the classpath is incomplete in Eclipse and lombok is not installed. Try and install the lombok plugin, a good tutorial on this can be found [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/lombok-eclipse-installation-examples/)

Comment: I mentioned in one of my previous comments that everything is installed. Still no clue why it happens

Comment: @Uata its not about installation, I am more targeting towards configuration.